# Does UIWebView leak memory?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, uiwebview

If your iPhone app uses a UIWebView, and loads many pages with large images, you may find that you are leaking memory. Can this be resolved?

Comment: My answer from a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609252/423171

Answer (score 6):

Try adding

```
[webView loadHTMLString: @"" baseURL: nil];
```

right before you release the webview. For a leak in 4.2.1 relating to displaying a PDF in a UIWebView this solves most of the leak problems for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known problem.

Marco Arment mentions the leak here.  http://blog.instapaper.com/post/60628543

There isn't a lot you can do.  One option in to "intercept" the html try to truncate parts that you don't need.  Obviously, this won't likely work for a general purpose webview.

In the meantime, you may just have to wait for an update from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I got a

> received memory warning, level 1

and then the application crashed with the huge text size in the web view.

[This article](http://www.codercowboy.com/code-uiwebview-memory-leak-prevention/) helped me, solving the leak issue. Very easy and straightforward to use.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it seems to help (looking at Leaks and running through simulator anyway):

```
MyWebViewController *myWebViewController = [[[MyWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyWebView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
```

It was the "autorelease" that seems to help in that the leak is not getting bigger on each webview I open.

Comment: @The-Kenny: Only if you don't actually use the view controller right away, in which case you should hold it in a strong/retaining property rather than a local variable.