# UIWebView leaking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiwebview

I have a class that extends UIViewController and implements the UIWebViewDelegate, like this:

```
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>{
    UIWebView *articleWebView;
    NSString *link;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    NSURL * safariUrl;
}
```

I'm trying to load a web page into the uiwebview, everything works fine, but i'm getting some leaks (like GeneralBlock-56, GeneralBlock-1024 etc) and i can't find out where they come from.
This is what i am doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (articleWebView){
    [articleWebView loadHTMLString: @"" baseURL: nil];
    [articleWebView release];
    articleWebView = nil;
}

articleWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,380)];
if (activityIndicator){

    [activityIndicator release];
    activityIndicator = nil;
}
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-24, self.view.bounds.size.height/3-12, 50, 50)];
activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];


link = [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
link = [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
link = [(NSString*) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes (NULL, (CFStringRef)link, NULL,
                                                             NULL, kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];   

[[self articleWebView] setDelegate: self];

[articleWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

[link release];

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
if (activityIndicator){
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator release];
    activityIndicator = nil;
    self.view = articleWebView;

}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [articleWebView loadHTMLString: @"" baseURL: nil];
    [self.articleWebView release];
    self.articleWebView = nil;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)dealloc {
    self.articleWebView.delegate=nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Along with setting the webView delegate to nil, you should ask your webView to stop loading. Add the following lines of code and then try:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.articleWebView.delegate = nil;
    [articleWebView stopLoading];
    [articleWebView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: @HD's thanks for your answer. That didn't help either. Besides, i think that the dealloc method does not get called when i am viewing the uiwebview, so i don't think that there is something missing from the dealloc - am i wrong? At the time the uiwebview loads and becomes visible, the leaks appear.

Answer (score 0):

If `articeWebview` is an `IBOutlet` why is it that you want to `allocate` it??

Comment: thank you so much for answering. You are SO right, at first i though i would make it through the Interface Builder, then changed my mind but forgot to remove the IBOutlet. I'll update my question. Anyway, removing it still leaves 2 leaks (GeneralBlock56, GeneralBlock-1024). Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Which object is responsible for the leak. Use the build and analyze and see how the leak occurs. Just make sure you release all the objects that you take ownership of when you no longer need them

Comment: I have already tried these. In Instruments, when i tried double clicking on the leak to see where it comes from, it just says "Unavailable", so i can't find out where the leak comes from. Anyway, thanks for your try :)