# ARC doesn't free webView allocated memory

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, automatic-ref-counting, rich-text-editor

I'm developing a `RichTextEditor` that user can add images that I transform to base-64 and after insert in `HTML`. When the User insert about 10 images, the DOM consumes a lot of memory to open and show the content. The problem is I see that ARC don't free all this content when I pop the `RichTextEditor` `ViewController`, making this way the memory continue allocated. I don't know what is the problem. If I open about 2 instance of this `RichTextEditor`, one to each different HTMLs, the memory uses grow up, and the app crashs. I don`t know how free the memory uses of this content, I thinked that ARCs does it.

Comment: This question might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018418/uiwebview-not-freeing-all-live-bytes-using-arc

Comment: Thank you yiding, but I don't see an answer there. The problem is really the same.

Comment: Hm, perhaps I don't get the question. Can you post a bit of code on how you are using the UIWebView and how you deal with the images?

Comment: First, I load the html that contais the functions of RichTextEditor using:
 `NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:@"cadernodemo/index" withExtension:@"html"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];`

After in ` - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad ` I read the HTML that was edited before, that already contain images and text.

Comment: `NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlfile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
            
            NSString *javaString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"javascript:loadFrame('%@')",htmlString];
`

And when this html is loaded, the memory increases a lot. So, when I touch to leave the RichTextEditor, I pop the navigationcontroller to dismiss the view, but this don`t release the memory. I tried a lot of ways, how remove the webview content, stop webview loading, nil the webview and so on. No way. In my conception, the ARC should do it for me.

Comment: Did you clear the delegate in the UIWebView? See the note here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I`m using NavigationController. I already tried nil Webviews delegate when I pop the ViewController, but the memory consume still the same. Also I tried nil the Webview, nothing changes.