# UIWebView with iFrame leak memory

Tags: ios, ios7, memory-leaks, uiwebview, youtube-api

I'm using Youtube's [YTPlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) which works perfectly fine it just leak a little bit of memory:

[image]

I get the exact same leak whenever I use iframe (regardless of the source). 
I know it's just a small leak but i'll sleep better at night without it.
Anybody knows how to get rid of it?

I think it might be related to this: [iOS7 UIWebView Memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738872/ios7-uiwebview-memory-leak)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421813/lots-of-uiwebview-memory-leaks?rq=1 check this link. I am not sure whether this solution is suitable for you. Just try it please

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. I think it's a different leak the library leaking is JavaScriptCore not Security/CFNetwork/WebCore.

Comment: Did you ever get rid of this? I have the exact same leak..

Comment: Cutetare, i haven't found a solution yet.