# iPhone OS 5 and UIWebView and ARC leaking memory

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiwebview, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to get my feet wet in iOS5 and ARC.  I'm trying to make a simple webview.  All I'm really doing is the following:

**In the header:**

```
    @interface MyWebView : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
       IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
       IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    }
   @property(strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;
   @property(strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
   @end
```

**In the implementation:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];   
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

When I check the Simulator and Instruments for leaks, I notice that there are small leaks (the red bars) being shown when I'm clicking around in the google site that I loaded up in the web browser.  Even when I dont click on any links in the webview google site, and I just let the page load up, I might see a small initial leak.

This code is really simple, so I'm not sure what's wrong.  Any advice would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Confirm (llvm 3.0 + ARC):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried profiling on an actual device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648396/does-uiwebview-leak-memory

Comment: Why is the IBOutlet on the ivars instead of the properties? Also on iOS 5 all IBOutlets that aren't on the top of the view hierarchy should be weak reference. E.g. if your webView is inside the UIViewController's view it should be weak reference in your class.

Comment: I checked it. And got a memory leak too. I did not use any `IBOutlet`, etc. Just plain `[UIWindow addSubview:UIWebView]`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with webkit...